# LPF (Low Pass Filter) block

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, technical-drawing, draw

I am trying to generate a LPF block with TikZ.

I have found out the option of drawing a LPF with CircuiTikZ:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em},
tmp/.style  = {coordinate}, 
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style= {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}
}
}

\begin{document}  

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [input, name=input] {};
        \node [block, right=20mm of input] (A) {A};
        \node [block, right=20mm of A] (B) {B};
        \draw [-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (A) to[lowpass](B);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This has **2 problems**:

1. The **line** connecting blocks goes through them, and does not start at their edge.
2. There is **no arrow** pointing towards the LPF

[image: Wrong LPF]

I have unsuccessfully tried to find a workaround to this.

Is there any way I could make it look like this?
[image: Correct LPF]

(As a last request, is it also possible to make the border of the block have the same **thickness** as A and B?)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: @Thruston Code updated

Comment: Forget it, I didn't read that you were using `circuitikz`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[box/.style={draw, thick, minimum size=10mm}]
    \node [box] (A) {A};
    \node [box, right=20mm of A] (B) {B};
    \path (A) to [lowpass, name=lpf] (B);
    \draw [-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (A.east) to (lpf.west);
    \draw [-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (lpf.east) to (B.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
if you like change `lowpass` border thickness, than you only need redefine bipoles thickness:

```
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
```

and above image you can redraw in:

[image]

complete *mwe* is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style = {draw, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=10mm},
     LA/.style = {-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
 node distance = 22mm
                ]
\ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
%
\node [box] (A) {A};
\node [box, right=of A] (B) {B};
\path (A) to [lowpass, name=lpf] (B);
\draw [LA] (A) to (lpf.west);
\draw [LA] (lpf.east) to (B);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Is it possible however to make the LPF block's border less thick instead of increasing A's and B's thickness?

Comment: @tuuli, see edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to not use path objects, but use them as nodes. I found this helpful in mixed graphs that are not pure circuit or block diagrams.
Most of the path objects do have corresponding shapes for the node, usually accessible by appending `shape` to the name.

In the example below this is `lowpassshape`

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    box/.style = {draw, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=10mm},
    LA/.style = {-{Latex[length=2mm]}},
    node distance = 22mm
                    ]
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
    %
    \node [box] (A) {A};
    \node [lowpassshape, right=of A] (lpf) {};
    \node [box, right=of lpf] (B) {B};
    \draw [LA] (A) to (lpf.west);
    \draw [LA] (lpf.east) to (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```