# Block of frequency response of a low-pass filter with a marked cutoff frequency

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, circuitikz, pgfmath

How to build in the rectangular block the amplitude-frequency characteristics of the Butterworth filter, Chebyshev and Elliptical Filters with a marked cutoff frequency?

Previously did not work in LateX / TikZ / PGF on this level.

I ask for qualified help.

**I need this sketch** [https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~kozick/ili/img1.gif](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/%7Ekozick/ili/img1.gif)

**And in block low-pass filter i need depict that:** https://dspguru.com/img/fig_f3.gif

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_filter

**My attempts were unsuccessful. I don’t even know where to start.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Cross}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex] \draw (0,0) -- (2,2) (0,2) -- (2,0);}}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{%
    block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=3em},input/.style={inner sep=0pt},       
    output/.style={inner sep=0pt},      
    sum/.style = {draw, fill=white, circle, minimum size=2mm, node distance=1.5cm, inner sep=0pt},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,thin,black}}}

\tikzset{
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
% for use this \tikzset yiu need to load in the preamble        %
% the folowing tikz libraries:                                  %
% arrows.meta, calc, chains, positioning and  quotes            %
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
alias path picture bounding box/.code=%
    \pgfnodealias{#1}{path picture bounding box},
CNTRL/.style =
{
          > = Triangle,
shorten <>/.style = {shorten <=##1, shorten >=##1},
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=##1,
    minimum height=8mm, minimum width=16mm,
    outer sep = 0mm},
dot/.style = {fill=##1,
    circle, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm, minimum size=1mm,
    node contents={}},
%
mlt/.style = {fill=##1,
    rectangle, draw=black, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={%
    \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
    \draw[very thick,shorten <>=1.5mm,-]
    (@.north west) edge (@.south east)
    (@.south west)  --  (@.north east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
%
sum/.style = {fill=##1,
    circle, draw=black, minimum size=6mm,
    path picture={%
    \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
    \draw[very thick,shorten <>=1mm,-]
    (@.north) edge (@.south)
    (@.west)   --  (@.east);
                },% end of node contents
            node contents={}},
% default styles settings:
   block/.default = cyan!30,
     dot/.default = black,
     mlt/.default = cyan!30,
     sum/.default = cyan!30,
}% end of CNTRL style
    }% end of tikzset

\tikzstyle{branch} = [circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0.5mm,fill=black,draw=black]
    

    
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=3cm, on grid, >=latex']
% Place nodes


\node[block,minimum height=2.8cm] (xi) {
\begin{pmatrix}
$\xi(\theta,\gamma,\Theta,\Gamma)$ \\ 
$I_{ph}(\xi,G_{exH},G_{0})$ \\ 
$P(I_{ph},V,R_{s},R_{sh})$
\end{pmatrix}};

% input half boxes
\node (n1a) [block,left = of xi]  {$\frac{1}{s+1}$};

\node (n1b) [block,above = 1cm of n1a]  {$\frac{1}{s+1}$};

\node (n1b) [block,below = 1cm of n1a]  {$\frac{1}{s+1}$};

\node [block,below = 2 cm of xi] (i1) {$I_{1}(s)$};

\node [block,below = 1 cm of i1] (i2) {$I_{2}(s)$};

\node [block,below = 1 cm of i2] (i3) {$I_{3}(s)$};

\node [block, right = 4.8cm of i1,minimum width=0.707cm] (prod1) {$\Cross$};
\node [block, right =4cm of i2,minimum width=0.707cm] (prod2) {$\Cross$};
\node [block, right = 3.2cm of i3,minimum width=0.707cm] (prod3) {$\Cross$};

\node [circle,draw=black,left =1.2cm of i1] (sum1) {$+$};
\node [circle,draw=black,left =2cm of i2] (sum2) {$+$};
\node [circle,draw=black,left =2.8cm of i3] (sum3) {$+$};

\node [block, right = 1.5cm of i1,minimum width=0.707cm] (LPF1) {$LPF1$};
\node [block, right =1.5cm of i2,minimum width=0.707cm] (LPF2) {$LPF2$};
\node [block, right = 1.5cm of i3,minimum width=0.707cm] (LPF3) {$LPF3$};


;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: better to give a handdrawn sketch of your requirement circuit

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388336/197451

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add a MWE of your current code. Especially as you mention "Previously did not work in LaTeX".

Comment: See my edit of question.

Comment: Could this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291849/38080

Comment: Hmm ... maybe this is what I need. I will work with this.